# Merging dictionaries in a list when members match

Tags: python

I have a list of objects with name, length and IP address. I want to combine these whenever the name and length are the same, joining the lists of IP addresses together.

That is, given the following JSON input:

```
{
    "Localfiles": [{
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 7911088,
        "FileName": "desktop.jpeg"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 7924192,
        "FileName": "Snelleplanga.mp4"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 282,
        "FileName": "desktop.ini"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["133.234.44.122"],
        "FileLength": 7911088,
        "FileName": "desktop.jpeg"
    }]
}
```

...the `desktop.jpeg` file, with length `7911088`, is present twice, with two different IP addresses. In the output, those should be merged, as follows:

```
{
    "Localfiles": [{
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158","133.234.44.122"],
        "FileLength": 7911088,
        "FileName": "desktop.jpeg"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 7924192,
        "FileName": "Snelleplanga.mp4"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 282,
        "FileName": "desktop.ini"
    }]
}
```

My current attempt at this is the following:

```
import json

jsonstring = '''{
    "Localfiles": [{
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 7911088,
        "FileName": "desktop.jpeg"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 7924192,
        "FileName": "Snelleplanga.mp4"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 282,
        "FileName": "desktop.ini"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["133.234.44.122"],
        "FileLength": 7911088,
        "FileName": "desktop.jpeg"
    }]
}'''

def test(data):
    dictionary = {}  
    dictionary['Localfiles'] = []
    s = json.loads(data)
    content = s["Localfiles"]
    for item in content:
        ipaddrarr = item["IPAddress"]
        ipaddr = ipaddrarr[0]
        filelen = item["FileLength"]
        filename = item["FileName"]
        dictionarychild = {}
        dictionarychild["IPAddress"] = []
        dictionarychild["IPAddress"].append(ipaddr)
        dictionarychild["FileLength"] = filelen
        dictionarychild["FileName"] = filename
        dictionary["Localfiles"].append(dictionarychild)
    print(dictionary)
test(jsonstring)
```

However, this doesn't actually accomplish the intended operation. How can I achieve my intent?

Comment: why is the last one added to the first? Is it because the filesize and filename are the same?

Comment: If, for example I have 2 external sources with different IP-addresses, and both have the same file with the same filename and filelength, I want both IP-addresses to be appended to an array like in the question.

Comment: Your question should specify that logic; right now it only speaks to what's "first" and "last".

Comment: BTW, if asking again, I would avoid framing this as a JSON question -- your data could just be Python literals, and except for whether `json.loads()` is called, nothing at all would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable data structure for this purpose is a map from (filename, length) tuples to IP address sets:

```
import collections

def collate(data):
    addresses=collections.defaultdict(set)
    for item in data:
        addresses[(item['FileName'], item['FileLength'])] |= set(item['IPAddress'])
    return addresses
```

Output is akin to the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> collate(json.loads(jsonstring)['Localfiles'])
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {(u'Snelleplanga.mp4', 7924192): set([u'217.120.103.158']), (u'desktop.ini', 282): set([u'217.120.103.158']), (u'desktop.jpeg', 7911088): set([u'217.120.103.158', u'133.234.44.122'])})
```

If you want to convert that back to your original structure, easily done:

```
def decollate(data):
    retval = []
    for (k,v) in data.iteritems():
        (file_name, file_length) = k
        retval.append({
            'FileName': file_name,
            'FileLength': file_length,
            'IPAddress': list(v)
        })
    return retval
```

...sample output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(decollate(collate(json.loads(jsonstring)['Localfiles'])))
[{'FileLength': 7924192,
  'FileName': u'Snelleplanga.mp4',
  'IPAddress': [u'217.120.103.158']},
 {'FileLength': 282,
  'FileName': u'desktop.ini',
  'IPAddress': [u'217.120.103.158']},
 {'FileLength': 7911088,
  'FileName': u'desktop.jpeg',
  'IPAddress': [u'217.120.103.158', u'133.234.44.122']}]
```

Comment: Side Note: For Python 3, replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using pandas:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

j = json.loads(jsonstring)
df = pd.DataFrame(j['Localfiles'])

df1 = df[df.duplicated(['FileLength', 'FileName'], keep=False)].groupby(['FileLength', 'FileName'])['IPAddress'].apply(lambda x: x.sum()).reset_index()    
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['FileLength', 'FileName'], keep=False)    
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

output_json = json.dumps(list(df.T.to_dict().values()))
```

Output JSON:

```
'[{'FileLength': 7911088,
  'FileName': 'desktop.jpeg',
  'IPAddress': ['217.120.103.158', '133.234.44.122']},
 {'FileLength': 7924192,
  'FileName': 'Snelleplanga.mp4',
  'IPAddress': ['217.120.103.158']},
 {'FileLength': 282,
  'FileName': 'desktop.ini',
  'IPAddress': ['217.120.103.158']}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
dtmp={}
for d in jsonstring["Localfiles"]:
    ip= d["IPAddress"][0]
    key= (d["FileName"],d["FileLength"])
    dtmp.setdefault(key,[]).append(ip)

lrslt=[ {"IPAddress":ip,"FileLength":lth,"FileName":fname} for (fname,lth),ip in dtmp.items() ]
drslt={"Localfiles":lrslt}
print(drslt)
```